# Using shortcuts in mac for debugging

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I read the following doc and when I use for example the f10
for stepping to the next line /function it doesn't work when I use the 
ctrl+ ' this is working but I want to use the Fn... buttons ,there is a way to configure it that the F buttons will work in debugging like in windows?

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/inspect-styles/shortcuts?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Fn + f10? On Mac that generally makes the function keys act as normal, rather than changing the brightness/volume etc.

Comment: Thanks, but there is a option to use it without the fn function, i.e. just click on F10 for example?

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to change in Chrome, however in `System Preferences > Keyboard` under the keyboard tab, check "Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys". This will change it system-wide, but will solve your problem.